# Syntax Error in Python in Try, Except Block

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I am running someone else's code:

```
./run_me.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 13, in <module>
    import options
  File "/Users/test/Desktop/lang-emerge/options.py", line 44
    except IOError, msg: parser.error(str(msg));
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried modifying the except block, but again I get an error:

```
    ./run_me.sh 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "train.py", line 13, in <module>
        import options
      File "/Users/test/Desktop/lang-emerge/options.py", line 44
        except: IOError, msg: parser.error(str(msg));

           ^
SyntaxError: only single target (not tuple) can be annotated
```

The code where error is:

```
 try: parsed = vars(parser.parse_args());
 except: IOError, msg: parser.error(str(msg));
```

Don't know what to do to resolve the error? The msg is a keyword in python try/except blocks.

With the modified code, `IOError as msg:`

I get:

```
./run_me.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 13, in <module>
    import options
  File "/Users/test/Desktop/lang-emerge/options.py", line 44
    except: IOError as msg: parser.error(str(msg));

                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: No, it's not a keyword. `except IOError as msg:`

Comment: That's old Python 2 syntax

Comment: @coldspeed thanks, i tried using IOError as msg, still getting an error..

Comment: @mourinho without the colon, not: `except: IOError as msg:` but `except IOError as msg:`. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: @PeterWood thanks, plz put it as answer, it solved the issue!

Comment: It would be better to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
except: IOError as msg: parser.error(str(msg));
```

You have unnecessary colon. You should remove it: Below code is the correct one.

```
except IOError as msg: parser.error(str(msg));
```